# In R dataframe, consolidate 5 columns with similar names into a single dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Given the following dataframe:

```
zed = data.frame(Title = c('a', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), TITLE = c(NA, 'b', NA, NA, NA, NA), "Title/Description" = c(NA, NA, 'c', 'd', NA, NA), title = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 'e', 'f'))
```

We'd like to consolidate everything down into one `Title` column. We can assume that in each row, there will only be 1 value that is not NA, and we are hunting for that value to add into the `Title` column. We can consolidate this down via the following approach:

```
yah <- zed %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Title = ifelse(!is.na(Title), Title,
                               ifelse(!is.na(`Title.Description`), `Title.Description`,
                                      ifelse(!is.na(TITLE), TITLE,
                                             ifelse(!is.na(title), title, ""))))) %>%
  dplyr::select(-Title.Description, -TITLE, -title)
```

however this approach is messy, and becomes even messier if the dataframe has 10+ title columns. this approach also breaks if a column is not present in the data:

```
# there's no TITLE2 --> ERROR
yah <- zed %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Title = ifelse(!is.na(Title), Title,
                               ifelse(!is.na(`Title.Description`), `Title.Description`,
                                      ifelse(!is.na(TITLE2), TITLE2,
                                             ifelse(!is.na(title), title, ""))))) %>%
  dplyr::select(-Title.Description, -TITLE2, -title)
```

any recommendations on how to (a) eliminate the nasty ifelse() nesting and (b) not throw an error if one of the columns is omitted.

Comment: Does this do what you want? `Title <- apply(zed, 1, na.omit)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` has the `coalesce` function that takes the first non-missing value:

```
yah <- zed %>%
  mutate(Title = coalesce(
      Title, Title.Description, TITLE2, title, ""
    )
  )
```

This will still break if one of the columns doesn't exist. I'd recommend identifying any missing columns and setting them to `NA` before running this.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to select only the columns that contain the the word `title` (regardless of case), then use `coalesce`. I also give the new column a different name, so that I could remove all the columns that contain `title`, then rename it.

```
library(tidyverse)

yah <- zed %>%
  mutate(temp = coalesce(!!!select(., contains("title")))) %>% 
  select(-contains("title")) %>% 
  rename(Title = temp)
```

**Output**

```
yah

  Title
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
6     f
```

Another option is to use `max` with `c_across`:

```
zed %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(temp = max(c_across(contains("title")), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-contains("title")) %>% 
  rename(Title = temp)
```

Or another option is to use `reduce` with `pmax`

```
zed %>% 
  mutate(temp = reduce(select(., contains("title")), pmax, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-contains("title")) %>% 
  rename(Title = temp)
```

Comment: hey! These are really creative answers. Why do we the need the triple bang for the coalesce reference? I am assuming it has something to do with NSE but I quite understand what the triple bang does